# Issue printing the results of a SELECT Query in VBA | MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Essentially I would like to run a simple select query that gets the sum of a column of values and prints the results in the immediate window (debugger).

**The following is an example of my query:**

```
SELECT Sum([Quantity]*[Total]) As Total FROM MyTable
```

**The following is my code so far:**

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT Sum([Quantity]*[Total]) As Total FROM MyTable"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
Debug.Print strSQL
```

How can I execute that query and grab the results of the SUM to Print?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT queries are not 'run', they are opened. Run is for action SQL - DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE.

Options:

1. Open recordset object and read value from calculated field.

```
Dim rs as DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Sum([Quantity]*[Total]) As Tot FROM MyTable"
Debug.Print rs!Tot
```

2. Domain aggregate function
   `Debug.Print DSum("Quantity*Total", "MyTable")`